# SharePoint 2013 hierarchical search question

Tags: 2013, search

we've a SharePoint Site with multiple hierarchically web sites like follows:

- Customer 1
- ---------Project 11
- ---------Project 12
- Customer 2
- ---------Project 21
- ---------Project 22
- and so on...
- ---------and so on...

All users have access to the level one with the customer webs. But users does only have access to specific project sub webs. So it's possible that some user has no access to any sub web underneath a customer.

No we want to create a search page where the user only see a list with customers he has access to at least one project sub web. So is it possible to create such a search query?

Thank you
Markus

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using security to prevent access to the sites you can use a query such as `contentClass=STS_Web`. If the sites are using a specific web template you could further refine the search by only selecting Customer or Project Web Templates.